# Перемещение и растворение блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку блок начал плавно перемещаться вправо и одновременно как бы растворяясь исчезнул?

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;" class="disolved"></div>
<button>растворить блок</button>
```

Js

```
$('button').click(function(){
  //что делать?
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(".block").addClass("slide-and-hide");
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}
.slide-and-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 200px);
  transition: opacity 3s, margin-left 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<button>растворить блок</button>
```